# Stored Procedure SQL Server Change column's size with data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to change the size of a column so I added this line in my stored procedure:

```
'ALTER TABLE '+ @tname+ ' ALTER COLUMN '+@fieldname+ ' nvarchar('+str(coalesce(@flength,50))+')'
```

But the problem is that if the column contains already data and they are bigger than the new size of the column it will raise an error. How I can check if there is data in the specific columng with size > @flength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `len()` function to find any columns that are larger than the `@flength`:

```
'Select * from ' + @tname + 'where len(' + @fieldname + ')>' + coalesce(@flength,50))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEN` function to check the size of your data

```
SELECT *
FROM   tname
WHERE  Len(fieldname) > COALESCE(@flength, 50)
```